# How to enable M.2 SSD storage on Asus TUF B360M-Plus Gaming?

Tags: bios, sata, nvme, m2-connector

I'm having an issue with my new SSD M.2 NVMe (1.3) device not showing up as a storage device. I entered the BIOS, but the M.2 device does not show up/it isn't selectable as a bootable drive. I can see it in the NVMe configuration settings in the BIOS, but I can't select it as a bootable device.

What are the steps I need to take in BIOS in order to enable it?

Comment: So is this M.2 device SATA or NVMe?  "I can't select it as a bootable device." - does it have an OS on it?  You are going to have to give us more information if you want an answer to your question.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I am getting confused by all the names. It is the ADATA SX8200 Pro, a 512 GB SSD. It is brand new, so it wouldn't have anything on it yet.

Comment: @Ramhound I just want to know if it's suppose to show up straight away when selecting bootable device, like hard drive does, or if it doesn't then what settings would cause it not to show up? Do I need to enable the port anywhere? I've already spent over 2 hours trying to make it work, it's not research but slavery with extra steps.

Comment: You can't select the device if it doesn't have an OS on it.  I don't even know "where" you can't select it.  I don't know if you are within an installation environment or within BIOS.  If the device has no OS on it, then it wouldn't be possible to boot to it, because it's not bootable.  Your question title indicates the device is a SATA device while the body indicates it's an NVMe device.  You should take some time to clarify your question.  Include screenshots if you have to.  The `ASX8200PNP-1TT-C` is a 512 GB M.2 NVMe SSD.

Comment: Did you put the m.2 on the top or bottom of the motherboard? it has to be on the top or M.2_1. Read the manual here (check pages 10 and 13): https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/TUF_B360M-PLUS_GAMING/E13794_TUF_B360M-PLUS_GAMING_UM_web.pdf